# Use own redirectUri when the Authentication expires

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

I got this action thats requires the user to be authenticated.

```
[HttpGet]  
[Authorize]
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string returnUrl)
{
   var vm = await CreateViewModel(returnUrl);

   return View(vm);

}
```

Now I've set a timeout for my users logged in session, but from the above action view. It will redirect the user to a page that is nonexisting on my application.
So I found the event: `OnRedirectToLogin` but I can't from that `context` find anything relevant from the action `Index` where the user came from so I can decide where to redirect my user.

```
services.AddAuthentication("Cookies")
        .AddCookie(options =>
        {
            options.Cookie.Name = "Cookies";
            options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
            options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
            {
                OnRedirectToLogin = (context) =>
                {
                    return Task.CompletedTask;
                }
            };
        })
```

Would it be possible to store/send `returnUrl` from the action `Index` to `OnRedirectToLogin` when the login expires?

UPDATED With the View:

```
<form asp-action="">
    @Html.HiddenFor(c => c.ReturnUrl)
    ....
    <div class="button-section">
        <button name="button" value="no" type="submit">Cancel</button>
        <button name="button" value="yes" type="submit">Ok</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access in the RedirectContext the request and query parameters. There you can read the returnUrl parameter and perform a redirect.

```
options.Events = new CookieAuthenticationEvents
    {
        OnRedirectToLogin = context =>
            {
                  var returnUrl = context.Request.Query["returnUrl"];
                  context.Response.Redirect(returnUrl);
                  return Task.CompletedTask;
            }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, that works when trying to update the page. But there is also an button on that view that preforms a POST and doing that the returnUrl is empty.

Comment: Updated with the View

Comment: @PresidentCamacho For `POST` method, what is your expected value for `returnUrl`? You could try store the `returnUrl ` in cookies and then get the `returnUrl ` from cookies in `OnRedirectToLogin`.

Comment: @TaoZhou I expect it to contain a redirectUri in the ReturnUrl. Is storing it inside of a cookie safe? I mean so noone can hijack it.